# Need Alternative Now For time()-Epoch

Tags: php, mysql

When I had started my site , I stored all of the time data in epoch format , now this has cause some problem to me , due to which I'm running into trouble , esp. as 2013 has come.

What I want to know is that, is there anyway that I covert all of the data( epoch format time) to human readable time within database?

My database has huge amount of data, else I would have had tried looping and converting each epoch stamp to human readable time. in the database.

Comment: As "epoch format" and "unix timestamps" are commonly interpreted as being the same thing, can you give an example of what you mean by "epoch format"?

Comment: Epoch format IS a unix timestamp as far as I know.

Comment: my bad I wrote wrongly corrected now, 1357919461 i want all db time data to be coverted to human readable time , within database

Comment: Use DateTime objects, which have a daterange that should satisfy most cosmologists

Comment: Something like `update yourtable set newfieldwithtypetimestamp = from_unixtime(theoldfieldcontainingtheepochtime);` should do the trick.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're facing, why are UNIX timestamps no good anymore?

Comment: because there are certain things i dont want people to add again, it is only alloed 1 per year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this without making a backup first!

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_column = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(my_column), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:s') WHERE 1;
```

Comment: it only returned years in the column o.O

Comment: Then you need to alter that column to set it as a type that can accept a datetime string, before you do the update. It's most likely only accepting the year because it's set as an integer type. It sees '2012-01-01 00:00:00' and just takes the first valid integer portion.

Comment: IMO you cannot do that in-place because the source and target data types are different, you need 2 columns with the appropriate types.

Comment: alright I fixed the problem , now it returned everything in the column (Y) , thanks a lot brother.!